# Disable background function for a two layer webpage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The webpage has 2 div

```
<div top> : This div overlap the under div unless the user exit it
<div under> : This div has a function, when user hover one of the item on it, it will process something
```

So, when the div top generate and overlay the under div, the mouse accidently hover on the page will trigger the function that under div .Are there any way to prevent it ? I just want all application focus on the div top when div top is shown. Thanks

```
var handler = function() {      
$('drag').unbind('hover', handler);
};
```

doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `return false;` or `e.preventDefault` to the function you wish to disable?

Comment: add to the begin of that unwanted trigger function? Will it affect if There is no top div?